# When is the SpaceShipTwo dropped from mothership?

Tags: virgin-galactic

When (after launching the mothership) is the VSS Unity dropped from the mothership and at which altitude?
I mean in space flights (above 80 km)

More or less, of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> WhiteKnightTwo uneventfully carried SpaceShipTwo to
> a release altitude of approximately 47,000 feet MSL.

[NTSB Accident Report - Virgin Galactic Party Submission](https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/NTSB/OpenDocument.aspx?Document_DataId=40429638&FileName=Party%20Submissions%20-%20Virgin%20Galactic%20and%20The%20Spaceship%20Company-Master.PDF)

The flight in the report lifted off at 09:19:30 PDT and released SpaceShipTwo at 10:07:19.27 PDT.

Comment: So at 48 min and 14 km.. Interesting, thanks. And how long it takes the whole flight?

Comment: Sounds like a new question.

Comment: The link has broken, and I can't easily find a replacement.  I found this [accident report](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR1502.pdf) on the NTSB website, but it doesn't appear to be the document you quoted from.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert well, that's annoying! I used it for another answer as well. Thanks for letting me know, I fixed the link. It's a bit weird though - it's a pdf but they have it tagged as html.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is a bit of variance in the altitude  at which the [VMS Eve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMS_Eve) mothership releases the [VSS Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSS_Unity) spacecraft.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSS_Unity_VP-03:

> On 13 December 2018, at an altitude of 43,000 ft (**13,000 m**), the [VMS Eve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMS_Eve) released the VSS Unity for its fourth powered test flight.

https://www.space.com/virgin-galactic-spaceshiptwo-launch-abort-spaceport-america:

> Things went smoothly enough early on. Unity lifted off beneath the wings of VMS Eve, its WhiteKnightTwo carrier aircraft, [around 10:24 a.m. EST](https://twitter.com/virgingalactic/status/1337780360587972611) (1524 GMT; 8:24 a.m. local New Mexico time [2020-12-12]). And Eve dropped Unity on schedule, at an altitude of about 50,000 feet (**15,000 meters**).

https://www.topgear.com/car-news/big-reads/behind-scenes-virgin-galactic ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201225040951/https://www.topgear.com/car-news/big-reads/behind-scenes-virgin-galactic)):

> WhiteKnight, the mothership, that will take Unity and its cargo of future astronauts to **14,600m** before releasing her to cover the remaining distance on rocket power.